How to determine whether the following examples are definitely assigned?
Given the following examples:
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int n=5;
        int k;
        while(n<6) {
            k=5;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}

and:
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        int  k;
        while(true) {
            k=5;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}

I know that the first example won't run properly because k hasn't been definitely assigned; while the second example can run through.
I also read the rough explanations given to a large number of examples in the earlier part of Chapter 16 of the JLS.
However, when I tried to use the formal definite assignment rules to judge these two examples, I was unable to make an accurate judgment on them.
The rules I'm using are from the JLS:

16.2.10 The while statement
• V is [un]assigned after while (e) S (§14.12) iff V is [un]assigned
after e when false and V is [un]assigned before every break statement
for which the while statement is the break target.
• V is definitely assigned before e iff V is definitely assigned
before the while statement.
• V is definitely unassigned before e iff all of the following are
true: – V is definitely unassigned before the while statement. –
Assuming V is definitely unassigned before e, V is definitely
unassigned after S. – Assuming V is definitely unassigned before e, V
is definitely unassigned before every continue statement for which the
while statement is the continue target.
• V is [un]assigned before S iff V is [un]assigned after e when true.

For example, when I'm judging the second example, if e is true, it seems that only the last rule can be applied, but this rule doesn't seem to be able to determine that k has been definitely assigned.
So, how can we determine whether the above examples have been definitely assigned according to the specifications?Thank you for reading and answering.

Out of all the bullet points, only the first one is the only relevant one, in order to determine whether System.out.println(k); at the end is valid.

V is [un]assigned after while (e) S (§14.12) iff V is [un]assigned after e when false and V is [un]assigned before every break statement for which the while statement is the break target.

The phrases "[un]assigned after e when true" and "[un]assigned after e when false" are special technical terms defined towards the start of the chapter. "[un]assigned after e when false" can still be a true statement even if the value of e is true.
From 16.1.1,

V is [un]assigned after any constant expression (§15.29) whose value is true when false.

So in the second example, both of the following holds:

k is unassigned after true when false
k is assigned after true when false

The point of this clause is to capture the idea of vacuous truth.
Obviously, it is also the case that k is definitely assigned before every break statement, so we can conclude that k is definitely assigned after the while statement, and k is not definitely unassigned after the while statement.
For the first example, "k is unassigned after n < 6 when false" holds, because k is unassigned before n < 6. "k is assigned after n < 6 when false" does not hold. See the sections 16.1.7 and 16.1.10 for more details. Therefore, k is not definitely assigned after the while statement, and also not definitely unassigned after the while statement.

Thank you. Then what about the first example? Is it because the definite assignment rules only recognize constant expressions, so that no rule (including the first one) can be used, and then the inability to determine that k is definitely assigned leads to the compilation error?

@user24723440 yes, see the edit and sections 16.1.7 and 16.1.10 for the relevant rules.

@user24723440 "Inability" suggests that we don't know whether k is definitely assigned or not, which is not quite accurate. The rules 100% determine that k is not definitely assigned.

You've gotten mixed up by the confusing sentence structure. The relevant rule here is in the first bullet point. Let's break it down:

V is [un]assigned after while (e) S (§14.12) iff

V is [un]assigned after e when false and
V is [un]assigned before every break statement for which the while statement is the break target.



That means that two conditions need to hold: If e evaluates to false, then V must be definitely assigned after evaluating e. Also, V must be definitely assigned before every break that breaks the loop. If these conditions hold, then V is definitely assigned after the loop.
In the second example, it is impossible for true to evaluate to false, so the first condition holds. The k=5; before the break; means that k is definitely assigned before the break, so the second condition holds as well. Thus, k is definitely assigned after the loop.
